# Unable to get rid of unwanted vblf char while passing innerhtml to a string

Tags: html, vb.net, html-table

I'm trying to get the `innerhtml` of a table into a string but `vbNewLine` were added:

This is the html code (I copied and pasted it from my browser):

```
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th class="tableHeader" align="center" valign="top">Xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx</th>
         <th class="tableHeader" align="center" valign="top">Xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="tableValues" align="center" valign="top">08/06/2015</td>
         <td class="tableValues" align="left" valign="top">Xxxxxxxx xxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx XXX</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

This is what I get in my string (look for `" & vbLf & "`):

```
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <th align="center" class="tableHeader" valign="top">Xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx</th>
      " & vbLf & "
      <th align="center" class="tableHeader" valign="top">Xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx</th>
      " & vbLf & "
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td align="center" class="tableValues" valign="top">08/06/2015</td>
      " & vbLf & "
      <td align="left" class="tableValues" valign="top">Xxxxxxxx xxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx XXX</td>
      " & vbLf & "
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

I tryed to get string in two ways but the result is the same:

```
SubTable$ = mTables(1).Cells(r * 3 - 2).getelementsbytagname("table")(0).innerhtml

SubTable$ = mTables(1).Cells(r * 3 - 2).innerhtml.ToString.Substring( _
     mTables(1).Cells(r * 3 - 2).innerhtml.ToString.IndexOf("<table>"))
```

I tryed to remove them using:

```
SubTable = SubTable.Replace(vbNewLine, "")
```

but it doesn't work.

I don't know if it can be important but it's a table nested into another table.

Comment: `SubTable = SubTable.Replace(vbLf, "")`?

Answer (score 1):

There are three possible line terminators: carriage return, linefeed, or both.

vbCr (chr(13)),
vbLf (chr(10)), or
vbCrLf (chr(13) & chr(10))

Probably your table is using one with a carriage return, with or without a linefeed.

Comment: I solved by looping subtable cells but thanks for your hint (+1)